# Problems integrating NMSSH in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nmssh

I tried to integrate NMSSh into an iOS-App (Xcode 12.2) and followed [these](https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH/wiki/Build-and-use-in-your-iOS-project) instructions, which is in line with what I found in this forum too.

Unfortunately I can't create the framework file as described. I selected my iPhone as device as recommended in posts within this forum. This is how it looks like:
[image]

Has anyone an idea how I have to proceed?

Thanks so much for your support.

Comment: Check the `Products` folder on the left panel. BUT since you seems to be a beginner, I'd strongly suggest you to use CocoaPods or Carthage for installing it in your app.

Comment: Thanks Larme, highly appreciate the support. Trying to use Carthage led to the error "Task failed with exit code 65". CocoaPods worked